# Why is C# Ado.net slower than Entity Framework 6.1.3?

Tags: c#, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I wrote some code to compare performance of C# Ado.Net and Entity Framework 6.1.3. I am calling a stored procedure which returns around 20,000 employee records and then map this data into List of "Person" objects. Then I ran 1000 iterations of this code and calculated the average time.

Here are the timings:

- Ado Net: 638 ms
- Entity Framework: 544 ms

To my surprise, Ado Net is around 100 ms slower than Entity Framework.

Ado.Net code:

```
    //GetAllPersons is a stored proc hosted in Local DB instance
    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("GetAllPersons", conn);
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    //Using Fast member library
    var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(typeof(Person));
    MemberSet members = accessor.GetMembers();
    var list = new List<Person>();
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        var person = new Person();
        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            if (row[member.Name] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                accessor[person, member.Name] = row[member.Name];
            }
        }
        list.Add(person);
    }
```

Entity Framework:

```
        var context = new AdventureWorks2012Entities1();
        List<Person> list = context.GetAllPersons().ToList();
```

The part of the code which uses SQL Adatper to load Datatable is the one taking most of the time. I tried using SQL Datareader instead but it was even worse. Am I missing something here because supposedly plain Ado.Net should be faster than Entity Framework?

Comment: EF is based on Ado.Net hence it cannot be faster than a pure Ado.Net implementation. However, you implemented a less ideal solution with a loop in a loop and other overhead. I reckon the internal EF implementation is smarter than that and possibly makes use of the context initialization instead of having an inner loop. Experiment: Have only one employee in the table and compare.

Comment: `DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)` is very slow. Rewrite code to using manual mapping - it's much more faster.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Yes, this makes sense. As you suggested, I ran the code for a single employee and Ado .Net was around 50% faster than Entity Framework. I kept on increasing the number of employees and reached threshold at around 100 employees when EF started taking over.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I want to avoid manual mapping because I am looking for a generic Ado.net code working with any entity.

Comment: If you want to avoid manual mapping then use ORM (EF, Linq2Sql, Linq2DB, NHibernate, etc) or micro-ORM (Dapper, PetaPoco, Massive).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Yes, Dapper looks like a good option. I ran the same test for Dapper with single, 100, 20K records  and it beat EF, Ado .Net in all scenarios

Comment: It cannot beat raw ADO.NET! It beat only `adapter.Fill`.

Comment: Didn't see any tools to count seconds, consider *StopWatch* in your code?

Comment: @LeiYang Sorry, I didn't post that part of code but I am doing StopWatch start and stop for my test.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Can you write your comment as an answer so that I can mark it.

Comment: @Ketan done. Added a link with more background information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Entity Framework (EF) is based on Ado.Net; see [What is Entity Framework?](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx) by the [Entity Framework Tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/). Consequently, EF cannot be faster than a pure Ado.Net implementation.

However, you implemented a less ideal solution with a loop in a loop and other overhead such as using reflection. I suppose the internal EF implementation is smarter than that and possibly makes use of the context initialization instead of having an inner loop.

Try this: Have only one single employee in your table and compare the results. EF is likely to be slower.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote that you tried SqlDataReader, but it was even slower. It should be the fastest, but since you didn't show your code, we can't offer suggestions. But here are some generic tips:

**1. Get column values by ordinal, not name.**

Rather than using `reader["column_name"]`, instead you should get the column ordinal, then use that. For example:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
  int col1Ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal("Column1");
  int col2Ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal("Column2");
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    int col1 = (int)reader[col1Ordinal];
    string col2 = (string)reader[col2Ordinal];
    // do something with col1 and col2's values
  }
}
```

**2. Avoid multiple gets**

The index operator is a method call, so avoid doing it multiple times for the same value. In your SqlDataAdapter code you wrote

```
if (row[member.Name] != DBNull.Value)
{
  accessor[person, member.Name] = row[member.Name];
}
```

As you can see, you're calling `row[member.Name]` twice. Instead, you should get it once and re-use the value

```
object value = row[member.Name];
if (value != DBNull.Value)
{
  accessor[person, member.Name] = value;
}
```

**3. Avoid reflection**

I've never heard of `TypeAccessor` or `MemberSet` before. From a quick search, it seems to be from a library called `fast-member`. Even if it's faster than .NET's built-in reflection, I'm sceptical about how fast it is. I know it's nice that it can significantly reduce the amount of code you have to write, particularly if your query has many columns. But, if you're trying to optimise for performance, particularly if you're unhappy with your code's performance compared to Entity Framework, you should remove that dependency and test what the performance difference is.

Comment: When using SQL DataReader, I was adding one row at a time to a Datatable while doing reader.Read() because I wanted my code to work for variable number of columns/different entities. I didn't really pay much attention to multiple gets because it is already fast. I have already tested performance of Fast Member library and found it around 50% faster than general reflection code.

Comment: In that case, what you benchmarked was comparing apples to oranges. A meaningful benchmark between two technologies must compare the same input and output, otherwise you're not comparing just the technologies, you're comparing different approaches with different technologies.